# Embedding function using tidyverse into shiny app

Tags: r, function, shiny, tidyverse

I am creating a shiny app that will take in a dataset and take user input to select a column by name, decide if the column should receive a treatment, an apply it if so decided. In this example, the treatment is to remove non-numeric characters and convert the cleaned column to numeric.

For this, I have decided to wrap functions outside of the app (in this example only one function that I called 'num_fix()'. My problem is that the app runs and returns a file, but that output is identical to the input, i.e. no changes to the target column. I have been bashing my head into this problem for a few days now and still can't fix it.

I suspect it must have something to do with data masking and properly referencing to variables within the tidy code in the function (Chapter 12 of the book 'Mastering shiny'), but still can't put my finger on it.

Help or some input on what I'm doing wrong/not doing would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

###Function 1: clean numeric column if needed
num_fix <- function(data, spalte) {
  satz <- as.double(gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", data[[spalte]])
  data <- data %>%
    mutate(spalte = satz)
}

###APP
auswahl <- c('yes', 'no')
ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput('upload','Your data'),
  textInput('abu', 'Column of interest in your data'),
  radioButtons("sauber", "Is the column already numeric?", auswahl),
  downloadButton('analyse','Return fixed data')
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$upload)
    
    ext <- tools::file_ext(input$upload$name)
    switch(ext,
           csv = vroom::vroom(input$upload$datapath, delim = ";"),
           validate("Invalid file; Please upload a .csv file")
    )
  })
  abundanz <- reactive(input$abu)
  test_saub <- reactive(input$sauber)
  
  
  reactive(if (test_saub() == 'no') 
  {data = reactive(num_fix(data(), abundanz()))})
  
  output$analyse <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      'abu_stet.csv'
    },
    content = function(file) {
      vroom::vroom_write(data(), file, delim = ";")
    }
  )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is indeed a good idea to isolate functions. That way you can test whether they work as intended.

I found three problems:

1. the external function `num_fix` does not return any values
2. within `num_fix`, you are trying to dynamically assign a name inside a mutate function. Instead, a new column is created named spalte.
3. you change the reactive value `data()` and reassign a value to it outside its own initial reactive statement. Either use data in a reactiveVal() statement and update the value, or use one reactive for the value `data`.

See below for a solution:

```r
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

###Function 1: clean numeric column if needed
num_fix <- function(data, spalte) {
  ## fix problem 1 and 2, now the function returns a data frame and 
  ## the new data replaces the old: 
  data[[spalte]] <- as.double(gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", 
data[[spalte]]))
  data
}

###APP
auswahl <- c('yes', 'no')
ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput('upload','Your data'),
  textInput('abu', 'Column of interest in your data'),
  radioButtons("sauber", "Is the column already numeric?", auswahl),
  downloadButton('analyse','Return fixed data')
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$upload)
    
    ext <- tools::file_ext(input$upload$name)
  # fix problem 3. combine the logic for reactive value data()
    return.data <- switch(ext,
           csv = vroom::vroom(input$upload$datapath, delim = ";"),
           validate("Invalid file; Please upload a .csv file")
    )
    if(test_saub() == "no"){
      return.data <- num_fix(return.data, abundanz())
    }
    return.data
  })
  abundanz <- reactive(input$abu)
  test_saub <- reactive(input$sauber)
  
  output$analyse <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      'abu_stet.csv'
    },
    content = function(file) {
      vroom::vroom_write(data(), file, delim = ";")
    }
  )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Of note is that I am not sure if the function `validate` is used as intended. It will also not display a message in the app. Maybe good to double check this

EDIT: if you want to use `dplyr::mutate` instead of Base R for the external function, an alternative would be using the `glue` syntax to make sure the right name is used (see also the [dplyr programming vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html), name injection):

```r
num_fix <- function(data, spalte) {
  satz <- as.double(gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", data[[spalte]]))
  data %>% mutate({{spalte}} := satz)
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for yor answer! Very helpful. I continue to have some trouble with the function itself, as it actually does not remove letters and the target column is still of the character type. In my original (non-function) code, it did work, but here I can't use the '$' operator as I did originally:  'satz <- as.double(gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", data$ad.u.juv.))'

Comment: Hi Tuck, the script created a new column in the data named "spalte" but I now understand this is not intended. See my edits in my answer above, does this solve your question?